# Why is the polygon not smooth?

Tags: modeling, polycount

[image][image: donut showing lack of smoothness]

I have done the set Shade Smooth, and deleted the faces then recreated it. It still looks like this.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recalculating normals.
In edit select faces/vertices and go to Mesh » Normals » Flip.
Alternatively you can use the Alt + N shortcut

Comment: Thanks man, it`s a normal problem, there is a extra polygon on the surface, which affect the normal vertex. Generally, it is the normal issue. 

thanks for your help. Have a nice day.